# .getFilesByType() does not seem to be working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a folder which may or may not contain forms and connected response spreadsheets.  However, the code below returns false even when these files are present.

```
  //checks the number of Google Forms in the subdomain folder
  var files = myFolder.getFilesByType('GOOGLE_SHEETS');
  Logger.log(files.hasNext());
```

This code returns true:

```
  var files = myFolder.getFiles();
  Logger.log(files.hasNext());
```

I'm imagining that I'm somehow getting the MimeType wrong, but as far as I can see [in Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) this is correct.  I'd really rather check specifically for these file types instead of just checking for files.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS

Try that instead of 'GOOGLE_SHEETS'. I'm not able to test it at the moment, but that is the format that the google documentation is asking for. Do take notice that there are not quotes around it.